# search a file containg an nmap scan with a block of 5 lines and only if 2 of the lines meet the requirements

Tags: file, sed, awk, grep, lines

any one know how to grep a file and look for 2 lines of information and only output those lines.  I'm performing an nmap scan on our network 10.1.1.x - 10.1.254.x and i'm looking for all IPs with port 22 open. Nmap creates my file but it contains entries with the following 3 types of entries

```
Nmap scan report for 10.1.0.1
<br>Host is up 93.1s latency).
<br>Scanned at (Date) (Time)
<br>Port    State     Service
<br>22/tcp  filtered  ssh 

Nmap scan report for 10.1.0.2
<br>Host is up 93.1s latency).
<br>Scanned at (Date) (Time)
<br>Port    State     Service
<br>22/tcp  open  ssh 

Nmap scan report for 10.1.0.3
<br>Host is up 93.1s latency).
<br>Scanned at (Date) (Time)
<br>Port    State     Service
<br>22/tcp  open  ssh 

Nmap scan report for 10.1.0.4
<br>Host is up 93.1s latency).
<br>Scanned at (Date) (Time)
<br>Port    State     Service
<br>22/tcp  filtered  ssh
```

I am looking to grep the file and return lines 1 and 5, and only if line 5 contains open.

I've tried: `grep -e '10.1' -e 'open' file.txt`

This nets what I want but returns every line 1 and also lines 1 and 5

I've tried: `sed -e '/10.1./,/open/!d' file.txt`

but this returns the same as using:  `cat file.txt`

Also tried `awk '/10/ && /open/' file.txt`

but doesn't return anything

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS=OFS="\n"} $5~/open/{ print $1, $5 }' file
Nmap scan report for 10.1.0.2
<br>22/tcp  open  ssh
Nmap scan report for 10.1.0.3
<br>22/tcp  open  ssh
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="";ORS="\n\n";FS=OFS="\n"} $5~/open/{ print $1, $5 }' file
Nmap scan report for 10.1.0.2
<br>22/tcp  open  ssh

Nmap scan report for 10.1.0.3
<br>22/tcp  open  ssh
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. The latter is exactly what I've been looking for.. Thank You all for your time.. Thanks again Ed..

Comment: @DavidGarcia You're welcome, if this is the answer you wanted, please click on the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `gnu awk`, you can do this

```
awk '/10\.1/ && /open/' RS="\n\n" file
Nmap scan report for 10.1.0.2
<br>Host is up 93.1s latency).
<br>Scanned at (Date) (Time)
<br>Port    State     Service
<br>22/tcp  open  ssh
Nmap scan report for 10.1.0.3
<br>Host is up 93.1s latency).
<br>Scanned at (Date) (Time)
<br>Port    State     Service
<br>22/tcp  open  ssh
```

This change the Record size from one line to one section.  Then you can get what you want.  You need also to escape the `.` or else it means any character and not `.`

To also search for port you can add it like this:

```
awk '/10\.1/ && /open/ && /22\/tcp/' RS="\n\n" file
```

Here is an version that will work with most `awk` version

```
awk '/10\.1/ {p=1} p {s=s"\n"$0} /filtered/ {p=0;s=""} /open/ {print s,$0;p=0;s=""}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `gnu awk`

you can using `awk '/10\.1\./ && /open/' RS="" file` if every 5 lines split by blank line